# Qual a diferença entre "==" e "is" em Python?

Tags: python

Usando as duas listas abaixo como exemplo:

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]
```

E testando:

```
x == y
x is y
```

O primeiro teste dá `True` e o segundo dá `False`. Por que o resultado é diferente nos dois casos?

Comment: Saudações Thiago. Eu recomendaria ter um pouco mais de cautela quando for criar uma pergunta aqui no site, pois o sistema possui penalidades automáticas para usuários com muitas perguntas fechadas. O que geralmente recomendo fazer antes de perguntar é acessar o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e discutir com o pessoal sobre a possível pergunta; se for duplicada provavelmente alguém já saberá indicar. Estou sempre online por lá e ajudarei no possível, principalmente em Python. Só tente não ser penalizado por algo simplório mesmo tendo a melhor das intenções.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` compara se as variáveis possuem o mesmo valor.
`is` verifica se ambas se referenciam ao mesmo objeto ou não.

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]

x == y (true)
x is y (false)
```

`x` e `y` possuem o mesmo valor `[1, 2]`, mas são objetos diferentes.

Comment: Só falta completar dizendo porque nesse caso são iguais mas são objetos diferentes, pois isso nem sempre acontece. Se for x = 2 e y = 2, x is y será True, diferente do exemplo da pergunta.